# Database method to work with any type of provider

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, design-patterns, factory-pattern

So far my program only dealt with *Sql Server* for any type of data work. I would like my program to work with *MySql* as well. And now that I making this change, I would like to avoid code repetition as much as I can. So I started thinking about having a *Factory Pattern* with two concrete factories `SqlServerFactory` and `MySqlFactory`. This will work! But many of my database methods have pretty much the same structure except that in one, we are using an `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and the other we are using a `MySqlConnection` and the rest of the method code is basically the same. Below is a example of one of my SELECT methods:

```
public DataTable GetSpyList()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cs))
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM SpyList";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I reduce code repetition by making the above method work for any type of data provider? Is this something that can be achieved by using [DbProviderFactories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: If you need to write portable applications, stick to ANSI SQL as much as possible. (Typical issues when not possible are date/time, fetch first/top/limit, and a couple of others.) The SQL Validator is a great time-saver when writing portable, ANSI SQL compliant, applications: http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml

Comment: u need dependency injection to your repositories, where inject i.e ado.net interfaces and any type of resolver where u register implementation of your current database provider.

Comment: check this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590511/where-how-do-i-handle-different-connection-types-using-repository-pattern-with-a

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the static DbProviderFactories and the DbProviderFactory class are fit for your purposes.

Of course, every abstraction like this is based on the common functionality of the base classes DbConnection, DbCommand, DbDataReader, DbDataAdapter.

For example. In the `MySqlDataReader` class you could find an overload of the method `GetString` that takes as input the name of the column to retrieve. This overload doesn't exists in the `SqlDataReader` and you need to use the ordinal position of the column to retrieve data. So, in case of `DbProviderFactory` you could use only the common version of GetString between the MySql provider and the Sql Server provider (IE using the GetString method that takes the ordinal position). Luckily, Intellisense helps a lot to avoid this error.

You could rewrite your code as

```
public DataTable GetSpyList()
{
    DbProviderFactory fac = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySQL.Data.MySqlClient");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using(DbConnection conn = fac.CreateConnection()) 
    {
        cn.ConnectionString  = cs
        DbDataAdapter da = fac.CreateDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SpyList";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses a fixed name for the Data Provider, but of course, you could read this name from some kind of configuration file and have your program change its underlying database changing the entry in the configuration file.

Comment: Are you going to change the string "MySQL.Data.MySqlClient" automatically to switch between these providers, or to pass it as a parameter to the method?

Comment: That depends on the context, This is just an example on how to use those classes. Being this a global condition that has to be set at the start of the program and cannot change while the program runs I would avoid passing that string as parameter to every method that needs this approach. I would use some kind of storage in the config file of the application and read that configuration at the beginning of your app, store it in a global readonly variable and use it whenever you need it.

Comment: You are right, I just wanted to address that issue because he is going to need it in his app.